# What should I do with the flatten layer during back-propagation?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm creating a CNN network without other frameworks such as PyTorch, Keras, Tensorflow, and so on.

During the forward pass, the `Flatten` layer reshapes the previous layer's activation.  I know there are a lot of questions about it, but what should I do with the `Flatten` layer during back-propagation? Should I compute the derivative of $dA$ and reshape it for the next layer or just reshape $dA$ of the previous layer?